# Submit Modal Render Controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a 2 CRUD Controller "Client" and "Equipment".
What I want :
On the "Client" Show.html.twig i want to add an "Equipement" via a Modal Page.

What already works :
Show the form in the modal via {{ render(controller('App\Controller\EquipmentController::new')) }}

The problem :
**When i Submit the form It doesn't create the equipment without message**.

My modal (body only) :

```
<div class="modal-body">
 {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\NasController::new')) }}
</div>
```

My equipment controller (only the new) :

```
    #[Route('/new', name: 'app_equipment_new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function new(Request $request, NasRepository $nasRepository): Response
    {
        $equipment = new Equipement();
        $form = $this->createForm(EquipementType::class, $equipment);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
    
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $equipmentRepository->save($equipment, true);
    
            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_equipment_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }
    
        return $this->renderForm('equipment/_new.html.twig', [
            'equipment ' => $equipment ,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

If needed i can give more code

Comment: Hi, does it reach `$equipmentRepository->save($equipment, true);` at all? If not then my guess is that your form does not have an action defined so when you submit it sends the POST request to your route that contains "Client" Show.html.twig instead of "app_equipment_new"

Comment: No it doesn't reach the submission. I've read that the problem could be that the post request is actually send to "client show page".
Where and how should i define the action to my form?

Comment: show us "_new.html.twig" please

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-http-method here's how you define the form's action (the second one using form options)

Comment: @hugoschweitzer you can post as an answer cause it works by setting an action and method in the equipment controller. Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default when submitting a form it will send a POST request to the url of the current page. If you want to send the POST request to a different url you have to define it yourself by adding an action to the form

In your case you would have something like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(EquipementType::class, $equipment, [
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('app_equipment_new')
]);
```

Official documentation for this feature is here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-http-method